# Change my answer to a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I've been accidentally posting my comments as answers and driving the moderators nuts since they change my answers to comments... I almost just did it again but caught myself. Is there a way that I can take my answer and convert it to a comment?

Thanks

Comment: My new favorite meta question!!! :P  Anyways, most of the time this happens for new users but I'm glad you took the time to post on meta. :)

Comment: LOL, i know Kit, you poor thing, I think you've fixed like 10 of mine over this week. Sorry about that!

Comment: No worries. I don't mind especially since you help answer a lot of question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry... that's a moderator function.  You'll have to delete the answer and re-post as a comment.

Comment: thanks, will do.